# When to use override in Scala class?

Tags: scala, overriding

Here's an example that confused me a lot.

```scala
class Point(val xc: Int, val yc: Int) {
   var x: Int = xc
   var y: Int = yc
   def move(dx: Int, dy: Int) {
      x = x + dx
      y = y + dy
      println ("x 的坐标点 : " + x);
      println ("y 的坐标点 : " + y);
   }
}

class Location(override val xc: Int, 
               override val yc: Int,
               val zc: Int) extends Point(xc, yc) {
   var z: Int = zc

   def move(dx: Int, dy: Int, dz: Int) {
      x = x + dx
      y = y + dy
      z = z + dz
      println ("x 的坐标点 : " + x);
      println ("y 的坐标点 : " + y);
      println ("z 的坐标点 : " + z);
   }
}
```

Why does the method `move` not need an `override` modifier? It isn't an abstract method in class Point, it should be decorated with "override", I think. Actually, when I add an "override", error happens.

And for xc, yc, why "override" is a nessesary?

I'm really confused with that.

I have python experience and very little Java experience.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: because `move` is not abstract in `Point`? Its simply a method. When you call `myLocation.move()`, it will call `Point.move()` unless you `override` in your child class. And by the way, your signature of move is completely different in Move and Location, so its not override at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for xc, yc, why "override" is a nessesary?

Nope, its not necessary. In your case you're making it `val` again in your child class, which is not necessary since you already defined them as `val` in parent class. *(simply remove val from child class)*

```
scala> class Point(val xc: Int, val yc: Int) {}
defined class Point

scala> class Location(xc: Int, yc: Int, val zc :Int) extends Point(xc, yc){}
defined class Location
```

> Why the method "move" doesn't need an "override"?

Because your `move` method in Parent class is not an `abstract` method
or your signature is different in child class than parent class.

eg.

```
abstract class Point(val xc: Int, val yc: Int) {
  abstract def doWhatever() : Unit
}

class Location(xc: Int, yc: Int, val zc: Int) extends Point(xc, yc) {
  override def doWhatever(): Unit = ??? // override is optional
}
```

You could have aldo `overrid`den if the signature was same, so that when you call `childClass.move()`, the overridden method is invoked.

```
class Point(val xc: Int, val yc: Int) {
  def move() = println("parent::whatever")
}

class Location(xc: Int, yc: Int, val zc: Int) extends Point(xc, yc) {
  override def move() = println("child::whatever")  //override is required
}
```

example invoking move method,

for a parent,

```
scala> val point = new Point(1, 2)
point: Point = Point@66813e6e

scala> point.move()
parent::whatever
```

for a child,

```
scala> val location1 = new Location(1, 2, 3)
location1: Location = Location1@233db8e9

scala> location1.move()
child::whatever
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand the "move" method explanation. However, for xc and yc, I removed the "override" and the interpreter told me "error: overriding value xc in class Point of type Int;
 value xc needs `override' modifier .....". Can you further check my code? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: did you remove `val` from child class, not parent?

Comment: I got it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Cool, happy scala weekend

Comment: "Because your move method in Parent class is not an abstract method." This is incorrect. Abstract methods don't require `override` keyword,  ever. Also the `move` in the 2nd class get away with the without the override keyword because it's an *overload*.